# Add Data Source Links to InfoPath from SP 2013 Data Source with Multiple Rows of Values & URLs

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, infopath-data-connections, multiple-values

I have six organizations with custom SharePoint 2013 Product libraries that contain four folders labeled as Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4.  Then I have a SharePoint custom list with one Title and one URL column. The Title column contains labels such as, "OrgA Q1 PRODUCTS", "OrgB Q1 PRODUCTS", etc. The associated URL points to the respective SharePoint document library with its associated Q1 folder. Therefore, the list has 24 rows of labeled URLs.

My InfoPath 2010 form has four sections for each quarter, so that if it is FY2018 Q1, the other three quarters are hidden. Each Q table includes a link that points to the respective Organization's quarter folder so that users can add images of their product samples.

I have a data connection to the custom list with the labeled URLs. When I add a link that I want to use a data source to point to the respective "Org Q1 PRODUCTS" label and URL within the custom list, how do I get the data source code to select the correct URL?

This code does not work:

```
xdXDocument:GetDOM("CCMDProductLibraryLinks")/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:SharePointListItem_RW/d:Title-Quarter("Org-Q1 PRODUCTS")/d:URL("")
```

What am I doing wrong?